# Cycles in arrays and hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I can not understand how the loop works, namely how it finds similar words and increments the value in the hash:

```
words.each { |word| frequencies[word] +=1 }
```

For example, if we enter: "This is the text in the array"

The output will be: This: 1, is: 1, the: 2 etc...

**How does the cycle detect that "the" occurred 2 times?**

```
puts "Your text, please: "
text = gets.chomp
words = text.split(" ")

frequencies = Hash.new(0)

words.each { |word| frequencies[word] +=1 }

frequencies = frequencies.sort_by do |key, value|
   value
end
frequencies.reverse!

frequencies.each { |key, value| 
   puts key+ " " + value.to_s  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because whenever you do `frequencies[word] +=1` it creates a key in the with value in the frequencies hash if it doesn't exist yet, and in the case that key already exists in the hash, then it increases its value by one.

Having "This is the text in the array":

```
frequencies = Hash.new(0) # Initial value {}
words.each { |word| frequencies[word] += 1 }
# first iteration:  { "The" => 1 }
# second iteration: { "is"  => 1 }
# third iteration:  { "the" => 1 }
# ...
```

Just when the word comes to the second "the" from the string, it increases the value of the key "the" in the frequencies hash.

By using `object += value`, you tell, sum to the one being on the left its current value plus the value on the right. As Sagar mentioned, it's equivalent to say `object = object + value`.

Note:

- `split` is equivalent to `split(' ')`.
- Instead initializing an empty hash, and filling by iterating an object, you can use [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object).

It could be simplified by using each_with_index:

```
words.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |word, hash| hash[word] +=1 }
```

Or if using Ruby 2.4 or higher, with group_by and transform_values (not fast as each_with_object):

```
words.group_by(&:itself).transform_values(&:count)
```

Comment: I suspect the OP doesn't know that `a +=  1` is equivalent to `a = a +  1`.

Comment: Maybe yes, I've added something to explain that.

Answer (score 0):

The neat trick is in this line:

```
frequencies = Hash.new(0)
```

That creates a hash where if you lookup a key that doesn't exist, then the hash will return 0.  For example, suppose you count the words in the following String:

```
"cat dog cat mouse"
```

Initially you have:

```
frequencies = {}
```

and ruby does the following inside the `each()` block:

```
frequencies['cat'] = frequencies['cat'] + 1
```

That line tells ruby to calculate the result on the right hand side of the `=` sign, then assign the result to `frequencies['cat']`:

```
frequencies['cat'] = frequencies['cat'] + 1   
                                   |
                                   V
                                   0    + 1 = 1
```

Because the 'cat' key doesn't exist in the frequencies Hash, `frequencies['cat']` returns 0, and the result 1 gets assigned to `frequencies['cat']`.  That leaves you with:

```
frequencies = {'cat' => 1}
```

The next time through the `each()` loop, the following line executes:

```
frequencies['dog'] = frequencies['dog'] + 1
                                   |
                                   V
                                   0    + 1 = 1
```

Because the 'dog' key doesn't exist in the frequencies Hash, `frequencies['dog']` returns 0, and the result 1 gets assigned to `frequencies['dog']`  That leaves you with:

```
frequencies = {'cat' => 1, 'dog' => 1}
```

The next time through the `each()` loop, you get:

```
frequencies['cat'] = frequencies['cat'] + 1
                                   |
                                   V
                                   1    + 1 = 2
```

Because the 'cat' key exists in the frequencies Hash, the *value* for the 'cat' key is returned, and the result 2 gets assigned to `frequencies['cat']`. That leaves you with:

```
frequencies = {'cat' => 2, 'dog' => 1}
```

The final time through the `each()` loop, you get:

```
frequencies['mouse'] = frequencies['mouse'] + 1
                                     |
                                     V
                                     0    + 1 = 1
```

Because the 'mouse' key doesn't exist in the frequencies Hash, `frequencies['mouse']` returns 0, and the result 1 gets assigned to `frequencies['mouse']`.  That leaves you with:

```
frequencies = {'cat' => 2, 'dog' => 1, 'mouse' => 1}
```

Therefore, when you create a hash with `Hash.new(0)` and you lookup a key that doesn't exist you get 0, but if you look up a key that exists, you get the actual value associated with that key in the Hash.